# App Engine taking Far Longer (> 1 sec) to serve static JS than static CSS

Tags: google-app-engine

(Question edited b/c I have realized it involves file type)

This file is 20kb. It is consistently taking > 1 second to serve.

`http://www.adrenalinemobility.com/js/ss-symbolicons.js`

Here is the *same file* with .css as it's extension:

`http://www.adrenalinemobility.com/js/ss-symbolicons.css`

It serves almost 1 whole second faster.

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: adrenaline-website
version: 1
api_version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: assets/favicon.ico
  upload: assets/favicon\.ico

- url: /css
  static_dir: assets/css

- url: /img
  static_dir: assets/img

- url: /js
  static_dir: assets/js

- url: /.*
  script: web.APP
```

I've also tried this `static_files` line (before the /js handler), and it was slow too:

```
- url: /js/ss-symbolicons.js
  static_files: assets/js/ss-symbolicons.js
  upload: assets/js/ss-symbolicons.js
```

Ways I have observed this:

- Chrome, Firefox (both on Linux) - from a DSL connection in Silicon Valley
- wget, curl, etc from that machine.
- Remotely wget and curl from a high-speed server at the University of Illinois
- Remote web testing services like webpagetest (see below):

Here's a webpagetest waterfall graph that illustrates this problem - notice the one file has a huge TTFB: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131101_ZQ_ZGQ/1/details/

If i manually set the mime_type to `text`, then it goes fast. `application/javascript`, `application/x-javascript`, `text/javascript` are all slow. Currently those files are serving without manually specified mime-type if you wish to test.

Some more info, as noticed by jchu:

The slow version serves with: `Content-Length: 19973` and the fast version serves with: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Still more details:

I usually get server `74.125.28.121`. Someone on reddit got server `173.194.71.121` and it seems to have even serving speeds between them. So maybe it's server/location dependent?

[Another post about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828450/browser-reports-a-really-slow-request-but-gae-shows-it-took-12ms)

[Here is a pastebin with full curl logs of requests for both files](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Je9nancP)

[Here is another pastebin with just the timing information from ten requests on each file in a tight loop](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Bh0TwHix)

Comment: Please show us the efforts that you have taken in this regard.

Comment: Do you understand app engine static serving? I mentioned that I use their cache infrastructure; There really aren't *any* other options that I know of. Please don't comment if you don't understand the domain of the question.

Comment: I am sorry for the careless reading on my part. So, you are implementing the static file serving or not? And, there isn't any other faster implementation other than their own `static_file` handlers.

Comment: I'm actually using the `static_dir` handler - I assume it should be as fast? I just don't believe that > 1 second to begin serving a static file is acceptable - something must be wrong.

Comment: Then, I am afraid you will have to provide more info. `static_dir` can't be the problem. At the very least, you need to show us your app.yaml

Comment: This might help. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/oX-bbQffjiY

Comment: Added my app.yaml. The problem is with the real server, not the dev server, so that post doesn't help.

Comment: This is an interesting observation.  I use static_files rather than static_dir, and do not set a mimetype and see no difference in load times between css and js.  (I have separate static_files directives for css files and js files and images). It might be worth a test to see if you experience the same perf problems switching to static_files and dropping the mime type.

Comment: This is puzzling. I ran this by some people on the team who know more about this serving path, and they didn't see any reason why having a mime type or not would affect the speed at which static content gets served. We did speculate that it might be an artifact of how the browser is handling mimetype-less content, and that this might somehow be being misreported. Which browser are you observing this problem in? I'm not able to duplicate the slowdown using curl.

Comment: Dave, I can duplicate it with curl (Just tested now, after the weekend, so that rules out some transient stuff too). I mostly have been testing with wget.

Comment: @Murph, I just did a GET of the css and js files just using Chrome.  I noticed that the response header for the css file has 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked', whereas the response header for the js file contains 'Content-Length: 6758'.  I'm guessing that this is affecting the timing before the first byte comes in for the respective files.

Comment: Another data point for you.  I'm in the Boulder, CO area & the server is: 74.125.193.121

Comment: I feel the same, was guessing they are doing some kind of virus scan before serving

Comment: They could just scan files once though - probably on upload. I really doubt Google would slow down the whole serving path like that.

Answer (score 3):

Add  mime_type: text   to your JavaScript static resource.

Would need to look into what mime_type is being assumed, what what clever trick is being done for text vs other mime types...

Comment: I get the same behaviour if I query the file multiple times in a single minute. 14:00:41: 1.272s, 14:00:46: 1.213s, 14:00:49: 1.077s

Comment: I wrote a bash script, and am not seeing any lag. It is very steady at around 100ms for me.

Comment: Same, and I'm using a very quick server to check from. Are you pulling the actual file (The cache not modified response is much faster)?

Comment: yes wget in a loop. Let it set 10 minutes, and you will see it slow. Pull it in a tight loop, and you will see it fast.

Comment: When loading your whole site, the only thing slow I see is: anonymoususerspace
www.linkedin.com/uas/js, but that is on the order of 100ms.

Comment: That's how I got my results, too. Check out the waterfall graph I posted on the bottom of the question - It's really just the one file that is slow

Comment: Regardless of what you decide, 28 files is way too much for a simple website. See if you can compress that down a little. Putting static content on a CDN with a different domain will allow it to download in parallel with your main page.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm going to improve everything. Really just started - I feel I should figure out this so I can decide what servers to use / if I have to move away from App Engine.

Comment: I've updated my question. it seems to be related to how App Engine is treating JavaScript vs CSS files.

Comment: does adding mime_type: text  to your JS directory do anything?

Comment: I've awarded you a bounty, it's a successful workaround. It disables gzip though, and I'd like to hopefully get a real answer as to why this happens / how to properly prevent it. So i'm leaving the question open for now :)

Comment: Found your question after posting mine. Same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828450/browser-reports-a-really-slow-request-but-gae-shows-it-took-12ms

Answer (score 2):

I've been seeinig the same behavior.

GAE has some strange edge caching behavior for these javascript files.  After the 4th or fifth consecutive request, the response time improves significantly (some type of edge caching of the gzipped content kicks in).  In my experiments it's gone from around 1.2s -> 190ms

I've been able to reproduce this consistently across 3 GAE apps.
If you use Chrome, you can go to the DevTools settings and disable cache (while DevTools is open).  Reloading the page a few times will get your javascript transfer times down to the reasonable numbers.

Google's edge cache probably has some logic where it determines it won't bother caching gzipped js files until they're requested frequently enough.  This would appear to encourage you to write a script that constantly downloads your js files to ensure that they download a few hundred milliseconds faster.  I suspect that the edge cache is smart enough to only cache for one region at a time though.

Comment: I don't see the speedup. I just did 100 requests in a tight loop, still the same slowdown. :/

Comment: Couple of things I noticed:  It seems to take a certain amount of time (about a minute?) before it's cached and quick, regardless of the number of hits in that first minute.  One big difference I've noticed between my test file 90KB in 132ms vs your file 7KB in 1.02s is that your max-age is 600 while my max-age is 2592000 (30 days).  Try playing with the max-age to see if it has an effect (but don't set your max-age on your actual file so high unless you're really ok with it being cached so long).  The other odd thing I see are some non-ascii characters in your script comments.

Comment: In case you want to compare, I'm trying with this file: http://www.dine-o.com/scripts/plate-min.f0cf34cb8f13329beea74604f191901a.js

Comment: Odd, mine never gets fast. I just did several hundred hits spread out with spaces in between them. I see yours as fast, though.

Maybe it has to play with content or size or max age.  Hrm...

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I also noticed yours never gets fast, which is why I suggested those other variables (since I'm not able to change them on yours).

Comment: Did you figure out the fix?  Your js now takes under 200ms to fetch.

Comment: I doubt that there was a real fix. The original .js file loads under 200ms but comes with Content-Type:text.