# Browser reports a really slow request but GAE shows it took 12ms?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, networking, yaml

HTML/CSS files load normally in my browser when doing a request on my GAE website, but .js files are insanely slow (all > 1s). The .js is in the static folder (just like the .css files).

The confusing part is that Chrome/Firefox report that it is "Waiting" for the whole time, but GAE's log shows a really fast request.

[image]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIqug.png)

The handler for js is identical to css, in app.yaml:

```
- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)
```

Edit, more info:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
- name: webapp2
  version: 2.5.1
```

- There is no concurrent requests going on for this test as I've requested the file manually from the address bar (as opposed to let the browser request it from its reference from the html).
- There is no cron jobs/tasks happening at that time.
- I don't see a new instance created, there is just one always available apparently (according to the Instance chart on the dashboard and to the log not showing "... has caused the creation of a new instance").
- The request is done directly on my .appspot.com sub domain.
- All my test are done with CTRL+SHIFT+R, the response is always a 200 (not from cache, not 304 unchanged).
- Results are the same when running in Incognito mode.

**I really wonder what's going on and where is the time actually spent.**

As I am typing this, I made some tests by copying /static/main.js into several new file names and folder:

- /static/main.css, request /main.css takes 180ms.
- /static/css/main.css, request /css/main.css takes 180ms.
- /static/css/main.js, request /css/main.js takes 1s.

Now for some reason, .css loads much faster than .js. But that's still not the 12ms reported by GAE's log.

Here are the requests / response headers:

Main.js:
[image]

Main.css:
[image]

The only difference I see is that, other than the extension, the css has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, while the js has `Content-Length: 7930` instead.

Comment: Duplicate with same issue, workaround, no real answer or solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731990/app-engine-taking-far-longer-1-sec-to-serve-static-js-than-static-css

Comment: what happens when you try to do this request outside of a browser? (w/ curl)

Comment: Same issue. I also tested with a browser from another computer/ISP and with curl from there too.

Comment: Just like suggested in the linked question, changing the mini_type to text instead of text/javascript or even application/javascript, returns the file in 180-280ms instead of 1.2s.